# How to programatically open html select options on ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, ipad

I tried with focus, select, triggering click/tap events but no luck.

I see Facebook sign up page implementing this.There is a exclamation mark. It will show up if you touch any of the birthday select control without changing it and then focus elsewhere. The interesting thing happens when you tap the exclamation mark on iPad Safari. The year options will show up. (It doesn't show on desktop Chrome which I'm using to type this ask).

So the question is how to implement the same behavior for iPad?

I put the picture of the Facebook sign up page at https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9DKU.jpg

Some code I tried:
    $('#someselect').val('test');
    $('#someselect').focus();
    $('#someselect').click();
    $('#someselect').prop('selectedIndex',0);
    $('#someselect').mousedown();
    $('#someselect').prop('size',10);

Comment: *"Look at the picture below"* where is picture? and what you have tried post some code here?

Comment: Upload image in somewhere like "imgur.com" and put your image link here.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a hidden `<label>` with some Javascript to show it if the dropdown's value is the default.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n1o00to6/)

Comment: Sorry, the question is about how to open the dropdown option list when you click on the icon instead of showing the icon. Thanks!

Comment: @dyt that's what a `<label>` does. Works on my iPad